# Wordpress как изменить ссылки только для конкретной таксономии

Tags: wordpress, rewrite

Есть структура ссылок к примеру site.ru/post/post_data/post_name/
как сделать так, что бы в поста, который привязан к кастомной таксономии "slider" структура была  site.ru/slider/post/post_data/post_name/ ?
А все остальные пермалинки остались прежними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработало для меня. 
Единственный минус в том, что пришлось ставить в линках где нет необходимой категории "news". 
И написать реврайт, что бы не выдавало 404 при переходе на страницу.

```
add_filter('post_link', 'locale_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'locale_permalink', 10, 3);

function locale_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%category_slider%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;
    if ($post->post_type != 'post') {
        return $permalink;
    } else {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category_slider');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'news';
        return str_replace('%category_slider%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
    }
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','remove_bare_folder_rule');
function remove_bare_folder_rule( $rules )
{
    unset($rules['([^/]+)/?$']);
    return $rules;
}
```